# try/catch not working on network image (Exception: Invalid image data)

Tags: try-catch, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, conditional-operator, networkimageview

I have get network image and used  ternary operator where I can show network image but unable to show default asset image where network image is invalid [default image in grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy07I.png) also as this-

I am new to flutter

```
 image: NetworkImage(products[index]
                                              .productImageList[0]
                                  )!= null
                                      ? NetworkImage(
                                      products[index].productImageList[0])
                                      :Image.asset("assets/defimg.jpg"),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight ),
```

it shows network image on index 0 but does not load  asset image where network image is invalid or null and throw this error-

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:5230:5)
#1      ImageDescriptor.encoded (dart:ui/painting.dart:5098:12)
#2      instantiateImageCodec (dart:ui/painting.dart:1998:60)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

after this i tried try/catch -my code with try catch is --

```
child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              try {
                                return Center(
                                  child: Image.network(
                                      products[index]
                                                .productImageList[0],
                                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                  ),
                                );
                              } catch (e) {
                                print("Got exception ${e.toString()}");
                                return Image.asset("assets/defimg.jpg", fit: BoxFit.contain);
                              }
                            }),
```

give me same error as above..

image response come from api in a list "productImageList" as shown bellow --

```
            "sellingPrice": "4000",
            "productImageList": [
                "https://www.xyzz.com/postadsimages/img/23682201.jpg"
            ],
            "createdDate": 1607754473000,
```

Answer (score 10):

[Image.network](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) lets you handle both the loading and error states of the network request, but not the way you tried.

I'll give you an example of what should do instead:

```
// Just to DRY
final Image noImage = Image.asset("assets/defimg.jpg");
final imageUrl = products[index].productImageList[0];

// Now, in the widget's image property of your first example:
image: (imageUrl != null) // Only use the network image if the url is not null
  ? Image.network(
      imageUrl,
      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) =>
          (loadingProgress == null) ? child : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => noImage,
    )
  : noImage;
```

This way you can handle the *Invalid image data* exception and also show another image while the network one is still being fetched.

PS: You can also use [FadeInImage.assetNetwork](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage/FadeInImage.assetNetwork.html) if you want a fading effect after loading the asset.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. Mind explaining how to use FadeInImage.assetNetwork? I tried replacing it with Image.network but FadeInImage.assetNetwork doesn't have the errorBuilder parameter. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! You've got an example [right in the docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images). To handle the errors you might use the _ imageErrorBuilder_ argument.

As I mentioned in the previous answer, you might want to read more about FadeInImage.assetNetwork [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage/FadeInImage.assetNetwork.html)

Comment: Unfortunately the errorBuilder does not catch the exception - is there any way to do this? It's kind of annoying since the debugger will stop execution at the exception, even if errorBuilder is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

**[CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)**

you can use the cachedNetworkImage instead of the image network.

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl:
                      "https://store4.gofile.io/download/361b6d89-e4a7-4444-a725-a32bdbfefba6/WhatsApp%20Image%202021-11-03%20at%209.38.00%20PM.jpeg",
                  height: 25.h,
                  width: 100.w,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                )
```

**OR**

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: imageURL,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  placeholder: (context, url) => Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 2, color: MyColors.primary),
                  ),
                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                      Icon(Icons.person, color: MyColors.grey),
                )
```