# Flutter Network Image fails with "invalid image data" on some images

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I am scraping some images from any kind of websites. And I need to calculate their `Size`. For that I found that `function` which is working for *most* of the cases:

```
Future<Size> calculateImageDimension(String imageUrl) {
  Completer<Size> completer = Completer();
  late Image image;
  image = Image.network(
    imageUrl,
  );

  image.image.resolve(const ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
    ImageStreamListener(
      (ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
        var myImage = image.image;
        Size size = Size(myImage.width.toDouble(), myImage.height.toDouble());
        if (!completer.isCompleted) {
          completer.complete(size);
        }
      },
    ),
  );

  return completer.future;
}
```

**Problem**:

The function above fails with

> Exception: Invalid image data

when calling it with this `imageUrl`:

```
https://static.zara.net/photos///contents/cm/media-transformations/joinlife-ctx/joinlife-large.svg?ts=1611919362013
```

What's the issue here? Also I couldn't `catch` the `Exeption`...

I found this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639376/try-catch-not-working-on-network-image-exception-invalid-image-data). But its not helping me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20910#issuecomment-617424037) on Git and it works for my quite well. It is rather a workaround than a solution:

```
Future<bool> hasValidImageData(String url,BuildContext context) async {
    bool hasNoError=true;
    var output=Completer<bool>();
    precacheImage(
        NetworkImage(url),
        context,
        onError: (e,stackTrace)=>hasNoError=false,
    ).then((_)=>output.complete(hasNoError));
    return output.future;
  }
```

it makes use of the `onError` that `precacheImage` come with. A downside is that it needs the `BuildContext` but like I said, its working for me and the only workaround I found.